# How to use jQuery :not selector for more than one element at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the jquery :not selector in such a way that when a bunch of elements don't have a specified class, then i want to add a class to one of them.

What I want to achieve is:
'when design-preview1, design-preview2 design-preview 3 and design-preview 4 do not have the class "selected", add class "selected" to "design-preview1" '.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
   $(".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4").not(".selected").$(".design-preview1").addClass('selected');
    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

**New**

This is my full jQuery code:

```
$('.pop-design1').click(function(){
            $(".design-preview li:not(.design-preview2).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-list li:not(.design-list2).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-preview2").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".design-list2").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".overlay").toggle();
        });
        $('.pop-design2').click(function(){
            $(".design-preview li:not(.design-preview3).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-list li:not(.design-list3).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-preview3").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".design-list3").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".overlay").toggle();
        });
        $('.pop-design3').click(function(){
            $(".design-preview li:not(.design-preview4).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-list li:not(.design-list4).selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(".design-preview4").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".design-list4").toggleClass('selected');
            $(".overlay").toggle();
        });
        if ($('.design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4').not('.selected').length) {
    $('.design-preview1').addClass('selected');
```

Basically what I want is that when .design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3 and .design-preview4 are not showing or are not selected, I want .design-preview1 to show by default.

**Live link:**
http://www.expertfrontend.com/test/2.html

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is: when design-preview1, design-preview2
>   design-preview 3 and design-preview 4 do not have the class
>   "selected", add class "selected" to "design-preview1"

As requested in your question, you said you want to use `.not()` to achieve this. Below is a way you can do this via the `addSelectedClassIfNotExists()` function.

You can also refactor your click listeners, so you only run one defined function. Below is what your modified code from your question could look like after the suggested changes:

```
var previews = $('.design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4');

function addSelectedClassIfNotExists() {
    if (previews.not('.selected').length === previews.length) {
        $('.design-preview1').addClass('selected');
    }
}

function toggleClasses(num) {
    $('.design-preview li:not(.design-preview' + num + ').selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('.design-list li:not(.design-list' + num + ').selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('.design-preview' + num).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.design-list' + num).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.overlay').toggle();
}

previews.click(function () {
    toggleClasses(this.className.slice(-1));
    addSelectedClassIfNotExists();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not achieve what I want. I have updated the question with more details, please check it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: hmm.. still not working. i think since the previous code says that on click remove .selected from .design-preview1 so we need a script that says on clicking twice it should add it again, meaning adding the script to an 'event' = mouseclick

Comment: not working. i think we need a different mindset for this. something like "on every second instance of clicks of the following buttons '.pop-design1, pop-design2, .pop-design3' add a class of selected to 'design-preview1'

Comment: this gives an error "dealWithClasses is not defined

Answer (score 9):

`:not` is a little too simple for what you are trying to do, as you need to change the class of multiple elements, and not all the same way. So, you're going to need a few steps. Among other things, you need to use the `.filter` method to determine whether any of your tags have the `selected` class:

```
var group = ".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4",
    $group = $(group);

function doDefaultSelection() {
    if ($(".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4")
        .filter(".selected").length === 0) { // note use of .filter here
        $(".design-preview1").addClass('selected');
    }
}

doDefaultSelection();

$group.click(
    function() {
        $group.not(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        doDefaultSelection();
    }
);
```

The default selector function (`doDefaultSelection`) selects all elements with your designated classes, picks only ones that have the `selected` class, and checks to see if there are any left. If there are no matching elements, then it adds the `selected` class to the `.design-preview1` element(s).

The click handler turns off the `selected` class for everything except for the clicked element, then toggles the class for the one you clicked on. It then sets the default again if necessary.

## Demo

```js
var group = ".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4",
    $group = $(group);

function doDefaultSelection() {
    if ($(".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4")
        .filter(".selected").length === 0) {
        $(".design-preview1").addClass('selected');
    }
}

doDefaultSelection();

$group.click(
    function() {
        $group.not(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        doDefaultSelection();
    }
);
```

```css
.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="design-preview1">blah</p>
<p class="design-preview2">blah</p>
<p class="design-preview3">blah</p>
<p class="design-preview4">blah</p>
```

Comment: not working. i think we need a different mindset for this. something like "on every second instance of clicks of the following buttons '.pop-design1, pop-design2, .pop-design3' add a class of selected to 'design-preview1'

Comment: I'm confused; what are you trying to do? Why are you asking about every second instance of clicks? If you want to toggle the class when people click, you will obviously need additional scripting, but that's not clear from your question.

Comment: Please check this link:
http://www.expertfrontend.com/test/2.html

on the left side, the small yellow circles when clicked show different images/content boxes in the screen area. by default the screen image is showing. but when view full design is clicked, the screen hides and the full design image appears. now if you click on the minus sign again, it would hide the full design image. Now i want the screen image to show again. Right now it goes blank, which looks pretty ugly

Comment: See my edits. I rewrote my answer, and it should work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if none of them has the class `selected` then you can use a `if` condition and add the class to `design-preview1`

```
if (!$(".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4").hasClass('selected')) {
    $(".design-preview1").addClass('selected');
}
```

---

If you want to check whether all of them has the class then

```
if($(".design-preview1, .design-preview2, .design-preview3, .design-preview4").not('.selected').length){
    $(".design-preview1").addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: this makes more sense. Unfortunately it is not working:

live link: www.expertfrontend.com/test/2.html

Comment: @AlexZahir do you want to check whether all of them has the class.... or just any one of them has the class

Comment: @AlexZahir If you want to check for all of them.. then what to do if `preview3` doesn't has but `preview1` already have the class

Comment: by default preview1 has selected. but onmouse click preview 1 selected it removed and whichever preview's trigger is clicked, its selected is added. but once it is clicked twice it removes its own selected. now nobody has selected. i want preview1 to have selected now, when nobody has selected. hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not selector something like this:

```
var elements = $("p[class^='design-preview']");
elements.each(function(para, i){
if(!$(para).hasClass('selected'))
{
   $(para).addClass('selected');
}
});
```

What I am doing here is selecting firstly all the para elements with the given class. After that I apply the loop on the array of returned elements and check if the current element has the `selected` class. If it does not have the selected class we add else we don't add.

Hope this logic helps.